# Reducing Vertex Cover (or Independent Set) to Vertex Cover and Independent Set at the same time

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, vertex-cover

In order to show that the next problem is NP-hard:

Problem: Vertex Cover and Independent Set

Input: Graph G and integer k

Output: Does G have a vertex cover of k and an independent set of k?

The sets does not have to be complementary (just about size k). I have tried to reduce Vertex Cover but I cannot find how to ensure that when there is a vertex cover in G, the problem above outputs true and deal with the independent set of the same size k. I have thought of doing something with the fact that vertex cover is the complement of independent set but since there is the same value for k I have no idea for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a reduction from Vertex Cover: given $(G, k)$ an input of VC, create a graph $G'$ with a copy of $G$ and an additionnal $k$ vertices with no additionnal edge.

Then $G'$ has a vertex cover and an independant set of size $k$ if and only if $G$ has a vertex cover of size $k$.